# How to add an external jars for developing a java service in webMethods Integration Server and webMethods Designer

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, webmethods

I would like to use an external jar in some Java Service (WebMethod designer 9.7). I see in Internet documentation that I have to put my jar in the package  /code/jars/ path on the Integration Server, and also in the build path of my project in eclipse.
But I dont know how to do this.

I have attempted to put my jar in `$swag_instance$/packages/$package_name$/code/jars`, with restarting IS, but I have compile time errors.

Could you please help me to understand what actions i have to do to doing that, using an external jar in a java service ?

Comment: I would need some more details to understand the issue. How are you creating the project? Is it through eclipse? whether you are using any build tool to do the builds for you?

Comment: I see eclipse tagged here. To add an external jar explicitly, you would need to right click on the project-->build path-->Configure Build Path-->Libraries-->Add external jars.

Comment: Yes, i use eclipse, with the webmethods service development view

Comment: Add the jars in the lib folder of your app. And build the project. It will be automatically added to the build path.

Comment: I have not any lib folder or build path settings. I use Service development view and package navigator (Software AG Designer 9.7). In java perspective, i have nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SoftwareAG webMethods Designer needs you to to add your external JARs to both:

1. The Integration Server package, in either the `./packages/<package>/code/jars/` or `./packages/<package>/code/jars/static/` folders depending on whether you need the JARs loaded dynamically and only available to the owning package or loaded statically at server startup and available to all packages respectively, and
2. **The Service Development Project 
   that Designer creates for the package in your Eclipse workspace 
   folder**.

You probably haven't done the second step and that's why your service won't compile or has errors.

Page 312 of the **webMethods Service Development Help** guide (version 9.8) has the following advice:

> If your Java service requires additional classes to compile, you 
>   must add them, either as individual class files or in jar files, 
>   to both the Service Development Project and to Integration Server. 
>   If you set up IS package dependencies for the Java service in 
>   Integration Server and there are classes and/or jar files in the 
>   IS packages required so that the service can compile, you must 
>   manually add them to Service Development Project. For more 
>   information, see "Adding Classes to the Service Development 
>   Project" on page 317. For more information about adding classes to 
>   Integration Server and how Integration Server stores package 
>   information, see webMethods Integration Server Administrator’s 
>   Guide.

Page 317 then describes how to add classes and JARs to the Service 
Development Project:

> Adding Classes to the Service Development Project
>
> If a Java service requires additional classes to compile, you must 
>   add them to the following locations:
>
> - Service Development Project in the local workspace so that 
>     Designer can compile the service.
> - Integration Server so that the server can compile the service. 
>     Designer does not automatically propagate classes that you add 
>     to the Service Development Project to Integration Server; you 
>     must add them to Integration Server manually. For more 
>     information about adding classes to Integration Server, see 
>     information about managing IS packages and how Integration 
>     Server stores IS package information in webMethods Integration 
>     Server Administrator’s Guide.
>
> Keep the following points in mind when adding classes to the 
>   Service Development Project:
>
> - You add individual class files to the `classes` folder of the 
>     Service Development Project.
> - If you have Java classes that are packaged together in jar 
>     files, you add the jar files to the `lib` folder of the Service 
>     Development Project.
> - If you set up IS package dependencies for a Java service in 
>     Integration Server and there are classes and/or jar files in the 
>     IS packages required so that the service can compile, you must 
>     manually add them to Service Development Project.
>
> To add classes and jar files to the Service Development Project:
>
> 1. Open the Project Explorer view.
> 2. Expand the Service Development Project for the Java service.
>      Service Development Project names use the following format, 
>      where packageName is the name of the IS package where the 
>      service resides, hostName is the host name of the Integration 
>      Server on which the service resides, and portNumber is the port 
>      number of the Integration Server:
>
>    `<packageName >[<hostName >_<portNumber >]`
>
>    For example, if you want to add class and jar files for the 
>      `order.orderStatus:checkStatus` service that resides in the IS 
>      package `Accounting` on the Integration Server with the host 
>      name and port number `ServerA:5555`, you would expand the 
>      Service Development Project with the following name:
>
>    `Accounting[ServerA_5555]`
>
>    For more information, see "Service Development Projects in the
>      Local Workspace" on page 308.
> 3. If you want to add class files to the Service Development 
>      Project, drag them from the file system into the `classes`
>      folder of the Service Development Project in the Project 
>      Explorer view.
>
>    When adding class files, ensure that you keep the structure of 
>      the Java package intact. For example, if you want to add 
>      `com.accounting.orders.statusClass.class`, you must first 
>      create the `com`, `accounting`, and `orders` folders within the 
>      `classes` folder as shown below:
>
>    - `classes`
>
>      - `com`
>
>        - `accounting`
>
>          - `orders`
>
>    Then add the `statusClass.class` file to the `orders` folder.
> 4. **If you want to add jar files to the Service Development Project,
>      drag them from the file system into the `lib` folder of the 
>      Service Development Project in the Project Explorer view.**

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation it usually to bundle the jar with the IS package that uses it so it is easier for doing deployment as a self-contained unit that migrates together with its dependencies.

So, putting it in `packages/(package name)/code/jars` should suffice to have it available for calling from within the Java services of that IS package.

Alternatively, if you want to make the jar available to all Java services across the IS, `packages/(package name)/code/jars/static` is a good place to put it.

See here an interesting wiki page describing the [webMethods Integration Server Class-Loading](http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/pwiki/-/wiki/Main/webMethods+Integration+Server+Class-Loading) mechanism and the several places in the order they are searched for jars, classes, and libs.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I tried to put a dummy jar (very simple one) in packages/(package name)/code/jars and i have reloaded the package. But compilation failed with namespace not found. I use webmethod designer version 9.7. But if i add in the same time, the jar in the local lib folder of the package, in the Java perspective, it works.

Comment: If you are placing the file in the server jars then you would need to restart the server for it to take effect. Once done, check the jars in the Admin page. Click on About link located top right corner. If you jar is successfully installed then it should be listed there.